# Getting OuterWidth of a Div using Jsoup

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, jsoup

I am working on a project where I need the outer width of a div on the server side. I am using jsoup for it.

How can I get the outerwidth of a div in jsoup, as we have outerWidth() function in jQuery?

Comment: I took a few minutes to review the jsoup.org website and I did not see any method resembling the jQuery `.width` or `.outerWidth` methods.  jsoup appears to be a HTML parsing and DOM creation package as opposed to a visual formatting framework, so specifics about how the HTML may be positioned or sized in a browser don't seem to be part of jsoup's functionality.  You need some sort of a virtual browser within Java, I wonder if there is such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the outerwidth of a div on server side because the server simply doesn't know the width. The real size of a element is depending on how the client renders the HTML and CSS. 
Think about `style="width: 80%"` on the topmost element. The real size is depending on the size of the browser-window.

I don't know nothing about the context of your question but if you really need the size of Elements on serverside and it's your own application you could let the client tell this information to the server.
If the question is just about getting the size of Elements with Java you could start a Browser with [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and check the dimension with [WebElement.getSize()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getSize%28%29).